# Would it matter if I make my column optional or not? (TypeOrm)

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

So we're trying to check our codes for possible bugs when a resource related to another is deleted. For example, we have a `Progress` entity which is related to `User`, which is then related to `Employee`. The `User` entity implements a soft-delete. If we delete a user related to a progress data, then `this.logger.log(progress.user.employee)` would return an error. Of course, making user optional (`progress.user?`) would solve it, but I was curious if making the `User` column optional in the `Progress` entity would make any difference at all.

So on the `Progress` entity, we have this:

```
@ManyToOne((_) => User)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
user: User;
```

I want to know if making this user optional would change anything.

Answer (score 1):

A soft delete is when you do not delete the row, but update `deleted_at` flag for a particular row. So a user should be always available. Could you add more context as to what you are trying to achieve. Try to be a little verbose in explaining your problem

Comment: I edited the question. I'm not sure if it's enough verbosity.

Comment: No it wont make a difference. What i meant to ask was from a domain perspective, whats the harm having Progress for an inactive/soft deleted user. As long as everything becomes read only, you should be good. Having said that, you can make it optional all the way to the db.. absolutely nothing wrong with that

Comment: We got an error with accessing progress from a soft deleted user since we're trying to get something like `progress.user.employee` data. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can check field progress.**user** at any request and delete relation if it already not exists